# Can not load script file in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am following instructions from 
https://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/in-memory-queries/

but when I try to load `calls.q` script file, I get:

```
q)l calls.q
'calls.q
  [0]  l calls.q
         ^
```

The same response is with trade.q file that was included in the package. 
I tried putting the script in `~/q` and in `~/q/l32` directory, but without effect. Database version is 32bit KDB+ 3.6 2018.10.23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just missing a backslash in front of the l:

```
q)l calls.q
  'calls.q
 [0]  l calls.q    
        ^
q)    
q)
q)\l calls.q
```

Hope this helps,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

The other way you can load a file in q session :

```
q)system "l calls.q"
```

`system` is internally defined as

```
q)system
.,["\\"]
```

This can be useful when you want to load a file based on some condition :

```
q) $[cond; system "l algo1.q"; system "l algo2.q"]
```